# Why is dill slow?

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.6, cpython, dill

From https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/dill.py#L43:

from pickle import _Pickler as StockPickler, Unpickler as StockUnpickler

This means dill inherits from ***pickle._Pickler*** which is a **pure Python** implementation. However, ***_pickle.Pickler*** is an alternative implementation of pickle and is a much faster version. Why doesn't dill extend from it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm the `dill` author.  I made that decision a decade ago, so let's see if I can remember... I believe the reason that `dill` uses the python pickler over the C pickler is that (a) I wanted `dill` to be pure python (there were no wheels, so distributing code with C extensions was less trivial) and (b) I wanted to be able to hijack the pickle registry so `import dill` would populate objects into the `pickle` registry.  I think that's the rationale.

Comment: Thanks for answering @MikeMcKerns (a) Making pickle pure Python is helpful in readability but there is a great trade off of comparison in doing so. For eg, pickling using dill takes around 30 mins while pickling using C pickler takes only ~30s. Performance in many scenarios, including mine, becomes very critical.

Comment: (b) As per my understanding, hacking pickle's registry is necessary for overriding dispatch functions for types like `types.FunctionType` for which pickle has pre-defined dispatch functions. For custom/other types, it is sufficient to use **copyreg** module. Are you implying that hacking pickle registry in case of C implementation of pickle (**cPikcle** in Python 2,7 and **_pickle** in Python 3.6) is not possible? FWIW, my use case is to pickle lambdas for which I need to override dispatch function for type `types.FunctionType`.

Comment: @SaimRaza: Like I said, it's been years since I thought of this particular topic... but I'm pretty sure I would have liked to use `cPickle`, but didn't for (a) and (b) above.  I can't say that it's not possible.  It might be.  I can say for certain that I didn't use pure python because it was easier... because I'd like speed as well... so at least at the time, it was for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though I still need to figure out some way to make C version of pickle work. It would be really helpful for a lot of people if you and other people maintaining `dill` would consider speeding it up by using C version instead of pure Python version of pickle.

Comment: @SaimRaza: you could try taking the entries from the `dill` registry table and plugging them into `copyreg`, or something like that.  Please, have a hack at `dill`... I welcome you to submit a PR that leverages the C pickler.  Or, if you poke around and run into a blocker, then post an issue on the `dill` GitHub page.

Comment: I will try to dig up some time for that.

Comment: I will get started with this soon. What would be preferred platform for discussing design and implementation changes? Github Pull Request/Issue, mail?

Comment: @SaimRaza: GitHub issue/PR is a good start, and we can go from there.