# Serializing lambdas and functions with dill. Is there a better (faster) way?

Tags: python, lambda, pickle, dill

Im writing a aio scrapper called scrubber upon lxml, httpx and asyncio. From beginning I wanted to outsource the cpu bounded parsing duty to a separate process.
After failing several times, learning about pickle and other issues concerning multiprocessing, I now found a way to let the process consume all that work. And Im a little proud of this solution also.

But it turns out, that the serialization I need is "terrible" slow, and at the end im not sure if this will have any advantage (I know - everybody warned me that serialization for mp could be a show stopper)
One of the problems is now of course the serialization with dill. dill package is needed because of serialization of lambdas. This I need to keep the namespace clear and give s smart and easy to use interface.

The test Ive done looks like this

```
import pickle
import dill
import timeit


# emulates the lambda a bit
def serialize_me(x):
    return 42 + x


p_t = timeit.timeit("pickle.dumps(serialize_me)",globals=globals(),number=10_000)
d_t = timeit.timeit("dill.dumps(serialize_me)",globals=globals(),number=10_000)
dl_t = timeit.timeit("dill.dumps(lambda x: 42)", globals=globals(), number=10_000)

dumped_p = pickle.dumps(serialize_me)
dumped_d = dill.dumps(serialize_me)
dumped_dl = dill.dumps(lambda x: 42)

ls_p = timeit.timeit("pickle.loads(dumped_p)", globals=globals(), number=10_000)
ls_d = timeit.timeit("dill.loads(dumped_d)", globals=globals(), number=10_000)
ls_dl = timeit.timeit("dill.loads(dumped_dl)", globals=globals(), number=10_000)

print("--serialize a function--")
print("pickle: ",p_t)
print("dill: ", d_t)
print("dill pure lambda: ", dl_t)
print("relative p/d: ", str(d_t/p_t))

print("--Compose that function--")
print("pickle: ", ls_p)
print("dill: ", ls_d)
print("dill lambda: ", ls_dl)
```

Resulting to

```
--serialize a function--
pickle:  0.018466599998646416
dill:  5.7938681000014185
dill pure lambda:  5.5841117999989365
relative p/d:  313.7485027252501
--Compose that function--
pickle:  0.017203299998072907
dill:  0.19668400000227848
dill lambda:  0.1924564000000828
```

Now, under real condition using pytest-benchmark the gap is not that big and lays 3-10 times slower but will not scale better than this.

But still far away from what one could await?
Yes I read this [Why is dill slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753612/why-is-dill-slow) and yes this was clear from the beginning, thats why I avoided dill, but at the very end the lambdas kicked in and become very useful.

Now the question is if I should kick that and hope, that parsing will not hang the event loop, dive down to realms of python to write a pickler for lambdas or what else?

---

Meanwhile Im using the `asyncio.run_in_executor` and removed the producer/consumer design.

I also found a solution to serialize lambdas but did not find a way to register it at pickle.

I will update this post as soon as I have it ready on github.

---

## Possible Answer

I made a small package. Available through github at the moment only.
This package works like a proxy using pythons marshall serializer.
It is about 100 times faster than using dill for this isolated case.

https://github.com/cloasdata/lambdser

`pip install lambdser`

Comment: If lambdas hurt... don't use lambdas. Even if dill was faster, frequent passing of function objects to a subprocess worker is going to be slower than using a named function that has already been imported anyway. As a design question... perhaps you could be putting more code into the subprocess workers in the first place. Whatever code is passing lambdas to subprocesses could potentially be encapsulated in a worker in the subprocess. Work hard a reducing that serialization payload.

Comment: Im not sure if I got the point. Instead of doing the lambdas each element, I should somehow "compile" them in front and only pass it no or one time to avoid serialization on each item. That could be an idea.

Comment: A lambda is just an anonymous function. Wherever you have a lambda, you could pull the code into a function defined at module level. The code object is the same, its just that it now has a name associated with it. If you are using a forking OS like linux, that named function is available to the subprocess without any loading - that's zero cost. In Windows, there is a one-time import of the module holding the function... but that happened anyway when python imported the module when the subprocess was first created (assuming you are using the multiprocessing module).

Comment: The problem is, that I just dont know at import time. The user may invoke something like this `lambda x: x[0].strip().split()[2].replace()` etc.

Comment: I added some optimization for the case user wont input a lambda. This gives a speed plus of about 15%. However, I need to do now some more investigation under real condition. The overhead for mp seems to be quiet big. Even then when removed dill etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the `dill` author.  Writing a new "python" serializer isn't the answer.  In fact, when you compare `dill` to python's `pickle`, the speed is roughly the same.

As you can see, they are about the same:

```
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 12:09:07) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> import dill
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> def doit(x): return x
... 
>>> timeit.timeit("dill.dumps(doit)", globals=globals(), number=10000)
1.315841937000016
>>> timeit.timeit("pickle._dumps(doit)", globals=globals(), number=10000)
1.1476000689999637
```

You'll note that I've used `pickle._dumps` which uses the python-based pickler.  In recent versions of python, `pickle` uses a C-based pickler by default (formerly known as `cPickle`)... and it's roughly 100x faster, as you experienced.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("pickle.dumps(doit)", globals=globals(), number=10000)
0.01674603300000399
```

So, you'll need to write a C-based pickler to compete with the speed of `pickle`.  That also means, that all of the registered pickling solutions need to be written in C as well, if you want roughly the same speed-up.  And then, you'll need to modify/fork `multiprocessing` to use your new serializer instead of `pickle`.

There is currently an effort in `dill` (and other serializers like `cloudpickle`) to better leverage the C pickling interface.  If you'd like to contribute to either, you are more than welcome to do so.

Comment: hello mike. I did not want to offend you or your works at all. I just was searching for a faster way, or ideas to do so.

Comment: I'm not offended. I just wanted to point you to the reason for the speed difference, and welcome you to write a C pickler (or to add one to `dill`). This is the only way to get comparable speeds to `pickle`'s C pickler.

Comment: finally made my own serializer based python. I did not check for particular edge cases but for my usage it works.

Comment: great news.  do you have a URL for it...?

Comment: https://github.com/cloasdata/lambdser